# Karate assertions for dynamic response

Tags: karate

**Response Actual:**

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "George",
      "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "id": 2,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a Database object where it return array of first_name's

**Expected:**

```
{"George","Janet"}
```

I am using scenario outline here as i have bunch of tests need to be check and output is dynamic. How can we write the assertions for this type of scenarios ???
something like response.data[].first_name == expected ??

Comment: I'm skipping this as it is too much to read. see if you can create a simple example in 5 lines or just wait for someone else. you can also read other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128679/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/58993029/143475

Comment: Hey Peter, As you said limited lines, please check

Comment: you already have an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: Array Match

Scenario: 
    * def act = 
    """
{
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "ad": {
    "company": "StatusCode Weekly",
    "text": "A weekly newsletter focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server, performance, and the stack end of things.",
    "url": "http://statuscode.org/"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "George",
      "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "id": 2,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Wong",
      "id": 3,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Emma",
      "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Holt",
      "id": 4,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Eve",
      "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Morris",
      "id": 5,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Charles",
      "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in"
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Ramos",
      "id": 6,
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg",
      "first_name": "Tracey",
      "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in"
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 2
}
    """
    * def exp = ["George","Janet","Emma","Eve","Charles","Tracey"]
    * match $act.data[*].first_name == exp
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get-short-cut

Comment: Neodawn, Thanks for the comment! will check on this and get back to you! one more question when i use print keyword for $response.data[*].first_name, do this print my first_name array?

Comment: Assign it to a variable using def and print the variable

Comment: `Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
  When method Get
  * def values = $response.data[*].first_name;
  * print values`  I am not able to print

Comment: Try it in the example I gave. It works for me. Also try printing your GET response to check if data is coming correctly first.